# How to grep for filenames found by find in other files?

Tags: grep, find

How can I `grep` for the result of `find` within another pattern?

That's how I get all filenames with a certain pattern (in my case ending with "ext1")

```
find . -name *ext1 -printf "%f\n"
```

And then I want to grep for these filenames with another pattern (in my case ending on "ext2"):

```
grep -r '[filname]' *ext2
```

I tried with

```
find . -name *ext1 -printf "%f\n" | xargs grep -r *ext2
```

But this only makes `grep` tell me that it can not find the files found by `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would tell grep that the patterns are in a file with the `-f` option, and use the "stdin filename" `-`:

```
find ... | grep -r -f - *ext2
```

Comment: Then I get from grep that *ext2 is not found (which is definitly false).

Comment: Found it now. Need to do `grep -r -f - --include="*ext2"` to work in recursive mode with pattern.